# take some values from other page

Tags: javascript, dart

I am totally beginner in dart,

I want to take some values from foreign page and show them on my page.

Foreign page

```
<div id="value1">
   35
</div>
<div id="value2">
   45
</div>
```

Is that actually possible with dart?
How?

Comment: Is this foreign page on a different domain?

Comment: Yeah foreign page, different domain. I can use php for server side scripting, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, Dart is compiled into javascript, so anything possible with javascript (including with libraries such as jQuery) is possible with Dart.

What you want to do is possible.

First you need to get the remote page. If it is on the same domain, you can use AJAX to get it from the client side. If it is on another server, you will face the same origin policy issue, and should set up a proxy. You can then download the page from the proxy, which could be implemented with many different languages, including php, or Dart itself (server side).

Once you have loaded the content locally, using AJAX (and maybe a proxy) then it is a simple matter of DOM traversal, to fetch the values you want, and inject them into your local page.

Comment: If the foreign server supports CORS, you can make a request to it directly. You may find https://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib to be helpful.